# PhpStorm local non-master branch auto syncing with local origin

Tags: git, version-control, phpstorm

I'm encountering behavior I just don't understand.

I have a local origin branch and another local branch called `Test-PHP-Storm`. Whenever I make changes to one, the other is automatically updated. I use the checkout command to switch between branches. I assumed I would have to merge the test branch into the local origin for changes to be applied. It appears that the 2 local branches are automatically synced somehow.

Does anyone know why this is happening and/or if this is the correct behavior?

Added log requested.
https://gist.github.com/nhaines888/cabb75857ba0c7dd312cbeb916824cd0

Comment: Please add the screen shot of  log history by any of below ways: **1.** version control window -> Log tab. **2.** terminal window -> input `git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all` -> add the output in your questions.So that your question can be better solved.

Comment: added the output in a gist, not sure if it contains anything related to the local issue.

Comment: Does it behave in the same way even if you do checkout from the command line?

Comment: @Naterade when did you create `Test-PHP-Storm` branch, after merging `nhaines888/readme-edits` into `master` (at `07f72d3` comit) or at `4a37a70`? Also please check in your local git repo .git/hooks, to check if there has the script in `post-commit` or `pre-push`?